# is it possible to store thread objects inside hashmap?

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, concurrency

I have scenario where I invoke some 10 `Thread`s, and each `Thread` has to wait till `Notifier` class notifies I want to notify specific `Thread`s, what I am doing is i am using `HashMap` with `Thread` id as `key` and the `Thread` instance as value. Later in the `Notifier` i am trying to notify it by traversing the map `map.get(threadId)` which gives `Thread` instance and I'm trying to call notify on that but it is throwing `IllegalmonitorException`. I am having doubt what to synchronise whether the `HashMap` or the `Thread` in both the `Waiter` and `Notifier` class..

```
package com.cgi.sample.jms.requestor;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class RequestorApplication {
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    public static String correlationId;

    public static String getCorrelationId() {
        correlationId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        return correlationId;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        Map<Long, Thread> map = new HashMap<Long, Thread>();

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            Waiter waiter = new Waiter(map);

            executor.execute(waiter);

            Notifier notifier = new Notifier(map);
            executor.execute(notifier);
        }

        System.out.println("All the threads are started");
    }
}

class Waiter implements Runnable {

    Map<Long, Thread> map;
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    public Waiter(Map<Long, Thread> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public void run() {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            Runner instance = new Runner();

            System.out.println("Executing thread " + " with " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

            long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();

            String threadname = Thread.currentThread().getName();

            executor.execute(instance);

            synchronized (map) {

                map.put(threadId, Thread.currentThread());

                try {
                    instance.wait();
                    System.out.println(threadname + "  Thread entered into waiting state!!!");
                    // Thread.currentThread().wait();
                    System.out.println(threadname + "  Thread woke up from wait!!!!!");

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}

class Notifier implements Runnable {

    Map<Long, Thread> map;

    public Notifier(Map<Long, Thread> map)

    {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public synchronized void run() {

        synchronized (map) {

            for (Map.Entry<Long, Thread> entry : map.entrySet()) {

                System.out.println("stored threads in map are--->" + map.get(entry.getKey()));

                map.get(entry.getKey()).notify();

            }

        }
    }
}

class Runner implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("runner invoked");

    }
}
```

Comment: *"is it possible to store thread objects inside hashmap?"* Yes, but that's not your problem. Your problem is calling `notify` on an object from a thread that isn't the owner of the object's monitor, as [the `notify` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--) tells you. As you haven't shown the `notify` call, we can't help you with that.

Comment: You should avoid synchronizing on Thread objects, and you definitely should not call `thread.wait()` or `thread.notify()`.  The reason is, the `Thread` class itself makes use of `wait()` and `notify()` for its own purposes.  A good rule of thumb is to never synchronize on _any_ library objects.  Instead, you can  make a `private final Object lock=new Object();` and synchronize on that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for your question is: **YES**. Because a thread is an object and it can be stored into a HashMap.

By otherway, and @T.J.Crowder told you, you are wrong in the way that you are using the notify. This i because you are invoking a **notify over an object who doesn't have the lock of the Thread** (`map.get(entry.getKey()).notify();`). Instead of you should invoke  the `notify` of the object `Runner` (`instance.notify()`), who has the lock of the thread, as your code shows us: `instance.wait();`

First of all! you must syncrhonize the block the object `instance` who will block the thread with the `wait` method, like:

```
synchronized(instance){ 
  try{
    instance.wait() 
  }catch(...)
  {
     //Do Something else
  }
}
```

And, call the method `notify` of the object `Runner` to stop waitting and continue the thread and leave the syncrhonized block, something like this:

`map.get(entry.getKey()).getRunnerInstance().notify();`

But, considere it, with your current code is so hard to implement this tips because you must rewrite several sections, for example: *the code where you are using object who lives into the context of a for loop to block a thread*.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

  Runner instance = new Runner();
  //...
  synchronized (map) {

            map.put(threadId, Thread.currentThread());

            try {
                instance.wait(); //You are blocking over a instance declared into the For Loop.
            }catch(..){
               //..
            };
  }

}
```

Comment: could you please show me how to get the RunnerInstance for the thread instance which is in the map.

Comment: Check this link: http://www.journaldev.com/1037/java-thread-wait-notify-and-notifyall-example